# What is the callback URL after calling repeat.vsp when using Form Integration?

Tags: opayo

I'm trying to do repeat payments with Form Integration in Sagepay (now Opayo).

From an earlier problem posted on here, I get that the securitykey is needed but is not returned in the Form call, so an additional call needs to be made to the getTransactionDetails command.

I have the securitykey and can now make a call to https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/repeat.vsp to initiate the repeat payment. However, the documentation does not say where the response to that call goes. I assume therefore, that it would go to the NotificationURL that is set up with a payment when using the Server or Direct integrations. Since I'm using Form, this is not set.

The question is, is there any way of capturing the response to the https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/repeat.vsp call if the initial payment was created using Form integration?

I suppose the second question is, has anybody successfully made repeat payments work with Sagepay Form integration?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you and we didn't do repeat payments; but we are looking at releasing deferred payments and I think it is a similar approach.

How do you make the call to 'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/repeat.vsp'?

Could you use a 'HttpWebRequest' to make the call then capture the direct response in 'HttpWebResponse'?

EG:

```
private static void DeferredSharedApiCall(Dictionary<string, string> data, string type, string url)
{
    string postData = string.Join("&", data.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value)}"));

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        tw.Write(postData);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        //log.Error($"{type} Error, data: {postData}", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log.Error($"{type} Error, data: {postData}", ex); 
    }

    if (response != null)
    {
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = tr.ReadToEnd();
            //log.Info($"{type} Response: {Environment.NewLine}{result}");
        }
    }
}
```